# Bootstrap - Not Working on Angular Child Components

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap via cdn on my angular project, bootstrap works on parent but not works on child child component width does not become `col-12`

Parent component width becomes 12 however child component width seems like becomes `max-content`. No `.css` file is applied.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


//parent
<div class="col-11 d-flex flex-row" id="section">
    <app-resume-section></app-resume-section>
</div>

//child
<div class="col-12 bg-secondary" id="resume-section">
    <div class="col-12 pt-4 d-flex flex-row flex-wrap gap-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-12 col-xxl-4 col-md-4">NEW RESUME</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you place the bootstrap.css? In index.html or?

Comment: @YongShun on index.html

Answer (score 0):

When using angular components to split the bootstrap code, you need to note, that the component, might not have the expected `width` and `height` in your provided code, that will be `<app-resume-section></app-resume-section>` to fix this, we can use the below CSS to ensure, that the component selector always takes the width and height of the parent, which might get your code working

The `:host` css selector will style the angular component and make it take the height and width of the parent element!

resume-section.component.css

```
:host {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/*

:host {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

*/
```